# Hibernate Query returns null value when stored procedure is called

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, stored-procedures, hql

I am trying to call postgreSQL stored  procedure to retrieve details of employee .
When i run this method , it returns null value .

```
public List<EmployeeAttendanceVO> getdata(String ListempIdString)
{

String startDayTime = "2020-05-22 00:00:00.000";
String endDayTime = "2020-05-22 23:59:59.999";
String ListempIdString = "'P1200',P1201',P1202',P1203',P1204',P1205'";
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

//Calling GETEMPDATA PostgreSQL Stored Procedure 
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM GETEMPDATA (ARRAY[:ListempIdString], :startDayTime , :endDayTime)");

query.setString("ListempIdString", ListempIdString);
query.setString("startDayTime",startDayTime);
query.setString("endDayTime", endDayTime);
query.addEntity(EmployeeAttendanceVO.class);
List<EmployeeAttendanceVO> queryResult = query.list();

return queryResult;

 }
```

It returns data when i run it in this way :

```
public List<EmployeeAttendanceVO> getdata(String ListempIdString)
     {

String startDayTime = "2020-05-22 00:00:00.000";
String endDayTime = "2020-05-22 23:59:59.999";
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

//Calling GETEMPDATA PostgreSQL Stored Procedure
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM GETEMPDATA (ARRAY['P1200',P1201',P1202',P1203',P1204',P1205'], :startDayTime , :endDayTime)");

query.setString("startDayTime",startDayTime);
query.setString("endDayTime", endDayTime);
query.addEntity(EmployeeAttendanceVO.class);
List<EmployeeAttendanceVO> queryResult = query.list();

return queryResult;

      }
```

Comment: Have you tried turning on SQL logging to see what SQL Hibernate is executing?  Variable-substitution is not simply String-replacement.

Comment: yup ,  I have tried everything . It only works when you pass Id's this way ARRAY['P1200',P1201',P1202',P1203',P1204',P1205']

Comment: Can you show how GETEMPDATA  is defined? And if you execute the query in a sql editor do you get data?

Comment: Yes when i  execute the query in a sql editor i get the data.